# Extract data from a pcap file

Tags: linux, wireshark, tcpdump

Is there any way to export the data section of all the packets from a pcap file?

For eg: the data section according to the image is `ffffffff72636f6e203434207174`

I tried searching a lot on web but could not get anything relevant

T.I.A

[image: Pcap File]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html), for example:

```
tshark -r file.pcap -Y "data.data" -T fields -e data.data
```